# Youtube iframe API...Can't playVideo() because of undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, youtube-api

I am using the Youtube iframe API to play videos using Javascript. I want the video the play initially when the document loads, then when you mouseout it will pause, then when you mouseover it it will start playing again, and so on so forth. What I am having issues with is how to get the video to play initially with `$(document).ready()`. I think maybe I need a way for it to detect the video is loaded because it says it can't `playVideo()` because player1 is undefined? The mouseover and mouseout parts work...

Thanks!

**EDIT:** The `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady();` loads more than 1 video.

**JS**

```
  var tag = document.createElement('script');

  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  var player1;

  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
      player1 = new YT.Player('video', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId: '7YRsdlkfH9c'
    });

    player2 = new YT.Player('video2', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId: 'vn-rlbsdfasd'
    });
  }

$(document).ready(function(){      
      playVideo1();
});

$(".top-left").mouseover(function () {
      playVideo1();
 })

function playVideo1 () {
      player1.playVideo();
}

$('.top-left').mouseout(function (){
      stopVideo1() ;
})

function stopVideo1() {
      player1.pauseVideo();
}

$(".bottom-left").mouseover(function () {
      PlayVideo2 ();
})

function PlayVideo2 () {
    player2.playVideo();
}

$('.bottom-left').mouseout(function (){
  stopVideo2 () ;
})

function stopVideo2() {
  player2.pauseVideo();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(document).ready` is firing before `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady`, so the video is not yet instantiated. You must move the initial playback to this callback function.
Remove the `$(document).ready` call and add the playVideoFunction to the API Callback:

```
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player1 = new YT.Player('video', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId: '7YRsdlkfH9c'
    });
    playVideo1();
  }
```

Comment: How do I do that specifically?

Comment: I don't think it works because the `playVideo1();` function is outside the `onYoutubeIframeAPIReady();` function?

Comment: Also, as a side note, I'm also loading multiple videos in `onYouTubeIframAPIReady();` , and putting the `playVideo1();` function in there renders the other videos to be unable to play.

Comment: The function declaration scope of `playVideo1` in your code seems to be `window` just like the script callback, it should work fine. Is it still showing `undefined`?

Comment: The error I get is: "Uncaught ReferenceError: playVideo1 is not defined"

Comment: Just checked the documentation online and it seems youtube api player has its own event that are fired when the player is ready, check this url: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

Answer (score 0):

In case someone still runs into this problem, here's what worked for me - I used the events object from youtubeIframeApi. In this example, I'm also using jQuery, so it must be loaded before this code.

```
          // Set up vars
          var $video = $('.video-popup');
          var player;

          // Load iframe API
          var tag = document.createElement('script');
          tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
          var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
          firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

          // If video activated the first time, run playback from within onPlayerReady event
          onPlayerReady = function(event){
              // Play the video
              $video.fadeIn(300, function(){
                player.playVideo();
            });
          }

          // If video was ready and stopped or closed, there won't be onPlayerReady event, so we must run video manually
          $video.fadeIn(300, function(){
              app.popupResize();
              // Just making sure player really has initialized
              if(typeof player != 'undefined' && typeof player.playVideo == 'function'){
                  player.playVideo();
              }
          });

          // Init video
          onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function () {
              player = new YT.Player('yt_player', {
                  height: '420px',
                  width: '100%',
                  videoId: 'example-id', // youtube video id
                  playerVars: {
                      'autoplay': 1,
                      'rel': 0,
                      'showinfo': 0,
                      'controls': 0
                  },
                  events: {
                      'onReady': onPlayerReady
                  }
              });
          }
```